# Save a plot as a png image

Tags: r

I have a plot that I saved it in an object called p.
[image: This is the plot]

I need to save this plot `p` as a `png` image that I like to name it, `"PICP.png"`, in the following directory: `"D:/data/results/images"`.
I was said that I can use the following codes:

```
png(paste0(output_dir, "PICP_", mla, "_", var, cm, ".png", sep=""), width=6, 
    height=5, units="in", res=1200)

plot(p)

dev.off()
```

The problem is that I do not know how to use these codes. How should I replace the objects in these codes with my output direction, object name `p`, and filename: `"PICP.png"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify output path and file name by `paste0`ing `output_dir` and the other variables. You probably need a `"/"` at the end of your `output_dir`. Note, that in `paste0` there is no `sep=` argument, `sep=''` is actually default. If `p` is already a plot (as I assume from your image) don't use `plot(p)` but `print(p)`, or just `p`.

Just make it in two steps for training.

```
## 1. make string
output_dir <- "D:/data/results/images/"  ## note the extra slash at the end

mla <- 'foo'
var <- 'bar'
cm <- 'baz'

(to <- paste0(output_dir, "/PICP_", mla, "_", var, cm, ".png", sep=""))
# [1] "D:/data/results/images/PICP_foo_barbaz.png"  ## specified path

## 2. put string in `png` as filenmame
png(to, width=6, height=5, units="in", res=1200)

print(p)  ## or just `p`

dev.off()
```

**Note:** If you just want `"PICP.png"` as filename,

```
to <- paste0(output_dir, "PICP.png")
```

is sufficient.

---

*Data:*

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point()
```